# Build cscope.out files in a separate directory

Tags: c, cscope

I've source code of a huge project in one directory (/my/src/) and I want the cscope files to be built in some other directory (/my/db/). How can I do that ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try following steps:

1 . Generate cscope.files

```
find /my/src -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' > /my/db/cscope.files
```

2 . Run cscope on the generated result

```
cscope -i /my/db/cscope.files
```

3 . Export to environment variable

```
CSCOPE_DB=/my/db/cscope.out; export CSCOPE_DB
```

Comment: So after creating the cscope.files, I need run cscope from /my/src and the cscope.out file will get created in /my/src ? or do I need to pass any flags. Right now, i'm passing -bqkR flags to cscope.

Comment: I had updated my answer. The option `-i` is to include that file, you can add any other options if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you have large number of files that are not part of git repo and if it is unnecessarily making cscope command slow. You can use below command to create cscople file (will work for java/javascript/python/c/go/c++ project).

```
git ls-files | grep '\.js$\|\.java$\|\.py$\|\.go$\|\.c$\|\.cpp$\|\.cc$\|\.hpp$' > /my/db/cscope.files
cscope -b -i /my/db/cscope.files
CSCOPE_DB=/my/db/cscope.out; export CSCOPE_DB
```